# Differentiate local imports from system imports

Tags: python, python-import

I just wrote this code:

```
import os
import helpers
```

And immediately I realized that later when I read this, I'll be wondering if `helpers` is a system module or one that I have written and put in the project's dir (I can't remember that much! :)).

**Any Pythonic way to make it clear in this code that `os` is a system module and `helpers` is part of my project?** I could write comments to that effect, but that wouldn't be great.

**How other languages handle this:**

- In C++ the problem doesn't exist because system includes are surrounded by `<>` while project-relative includes are surrounded by `""`.
- The C# solution to the problem is that functionality defined in any file in the current project is accessible without any import statement.

**Edit:** I found [a related PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) that introduces a `from . import someModule` syntax for importing project-local modules. I'm gonna try that out. But it's not enough. For importing system modules I still only have the generic `import blah` syntax.

Comment: I don't know if there's a language specific mechanism for what you want. But you surely can write a context manager that manipulates `sys.path` and imports only from either installed packages or project specific packages. Although this might help readability, maintainability would be a PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In several companies I've worked at and several open source projects I've seen, this is simply done by coding convention of separating import statements into groups, with newlines splitting them.

The groups are always in this order: core library imports, followed by third-party imports, followed by first party imports.

So an example of the grouping would be like this:

```
import os
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import requests
import termcolor 

from my_app import my_module1
from my_app import my_module2
```

Like many things in Python, this style is just a coding convention.  But it is a common one, so I think the groupings should be easily understood by most Python developers.  Indeed, it is even recommended in the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

There is a popular tool called [isort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isort) which can automate the process of grouping these imports for you.

If you want something more explicit, there is nothing preventing you from using relative imports for the same-project code.  Then it will be 100% clear that these modules come from the same package.